# Remove 10 trailing lines & add 1 blank line when a condition is met

Tags: text

I'm trying to build a back-out script for a change to a Panorama appliance that is managing 100's of firewalls.

Back History - We have identified 10,000+ un-used firewall rules which were disabled as part of a security remediation project last year.  Now that they have been disabled for months and to free up space on the Panorama device, we want to delete those disabled rules permanently from the Panorama appliance.  Our company policy states if we remove anything we have to write a back-out script to put it back on the device should it be found the rule was needed in the future.

To get the existing rules, I setup a capture and performed a show command for each rule.
I ran a command similar to this:
show device-group (group name) post-rulebase security rules (rule name)
Where the (group name) will be the same for each row, but the (rule name) will be different for each row (show command).  The group name will represent a group of firewalls 2+ and we will have 100-1000 different rules that have to be removed for that group name.

The output from the show commands will contain about 15 rows of legitimate information for each (rule name) but then is followed by 10 rows of information, 9 of which are not needed for the back-out script.

The last row of the legitimate information will look something like this
set device-group (group name) post-rulebase security rules (line number) disabled yes
(Note: "disabled yes" is the key to the last row)

Then after the "disabled yes" row, the next 10 rows will will include a blank row and 9 unwanted rows and look something like this

[K[?1l>[edit]
user@Panorama-ABCD(primary-active)# show
[user@Panorama-ABCD(primary-active)# show device-group
[user@Panorama-ABCD(primary-active)# show device-group (group name)
[user@Panorama-ABCD(primary-active)# show device-group (group name) post-rulebase
[user@Panorama-ABCD(primary-active)# show device-group (group name) post-rulebase security
[user@Panorama-ABCD(primary-active)# show device-group (group name) post-rulebase security rules
[user@Panorama-ABCD(primary-active)# show device-group (group name) post-rulebase security rules (line number)
[?1h=

Being new to python I'm not sure how to do this but - I would like a script that will read through my text file that contains 1000's of rows - when it finds a row that contains "disabled yes" as part of the row, it will skip 1 row then delete the next 9 rows.

Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe including a sample text file would make it easy to understand the use-case

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code tags for easier readability :)